# How to load data/update Power BI Dataset monthly

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've been asked to implement a way to load data to my datasets once a month. As Power BI Service doesn't have this option, I had to find a solution using Power Query and bellow I describe the step-by-step of my solution.

If it helps you at some way, please, let me know by posting a comment bellow. If you have a better and/or more elegant solution I'm glad to hear from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as my first solution didn't work, here I'll post the definity solution that we (me and my colleges) found.
I have to say that this solution is not so simple as it uses a Linux server, Gitlab and Jenkins, so it require a relative complex environment and I'll not describe how to build it.

At the end, I'll suggest a simpler solution.

**THE ENVIRONMENT**

On my company we use Jenkins to schedule jobs, Gitlab to store source code and we have a Linux Server to execute small tasks using Shell Script. For this problem I used all three services besides Power BI API.

**JENKINS**

I use Jenkins to schedule a job that run montlhy. This job was created using the following configs:

- Parameters: I created 2 parameters (workspace_id and dataset_id) so I can test the script at any environment (Power BI Workspace) by just changing the value of those parameters;
- Schedule Job: this job was schedule to run every day 1 at 02:00 a.m. As Jenkins uses the same sintax as CRON (I thing it is just a intermediate between you and CRON) the value of this field is `0 2 1 * *`.
- Build: as here we have a remote linux server to execute the scripts, I used a `Execute shell script on remote host using ssh`. I don't know why on Jenkins you can not execute the curl command direct on the job, it just didn't work, so I had to split the solution into both Jenkins and Linux server. At `SSH site` you have to select the credentials (previously created by my team) and at `command` are the commands bellow:

```
#Navigate to the script shell directory
cd "script-shell-script/"

# pulls the last version of the script. If you aren't using Gitlab,
# remove this command
git pull

# every time git pulls a new file version, it has read access.
# This command allows the execution of the filechmod +x powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh

# make a call to the file passing as parameter the workspace id and dataset id
./powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh $ID_WORKSPACE $ID_DATASET
```

**SHELL SCIPT**

As you already imagine, the core solution is the content of `powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh`. But, before going, there, you must understand how Power BI API works and you have to configure your Power BI environment to make API calls work. So, please, make sure that you already have your Principal Service properly configured by following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal
Once you got your `object_id`, `client_id` and `client_secret` you can create your shell script file. Bellow is the code of my `.sh` file.

```
# load OBJECT_ID, CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET as environment variables
source credential_file.sh

# This command retrieves a new token from Microsoft Credentials Manager
token_msg=$(curl -X POST "https://login.windows.net/$OBJECT_ID/oauth2/token" \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
   -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&client_id='$CLIENT_ID'&client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET
   )
# Extract the token from the response message
token=$(echo "$token_msg" | jq -r '.access_token')

# Ask Power BI to refresh dataset
refresh_msg=$(curl -X POST 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/'$1'/datasets/'$2'/refreshes' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '$token \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"notifyOption": "NoNotification"}')
```

And here goes some explanation. The first command is `source credential_file.sh` which loads 3 variables (OBJECT_ID, CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET). The intention here is to separate confidential info from the script so I can store the main script file on a version control (Git) and not disclosure any sensitivy information. So, besides `powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh` file you must have `credential_file.sh` at the same directory and with the following content:

OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID_VALUE
CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID_VALUE
CLIENT_SECRET=CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE

It's important to say that if you are using Git or any other version control, only `powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh` file goes to version control and `credential_file.sh` file must remain only at your Linux Server. I suggest you to save it's content into a password store application like keepass, as CLIENT_SECRET is not possible to retrieve.

**FINAL CONSIDERATIONS**

So above is the most relevant info of my solution. As you can see I'm ommiting (intentionally) how to build the environment and make them talk (jekins with linux, jenkins with Git and so on).
If all you have is a Linux or Windows host, I suggest you this:

**Linux Host**

On this simpler environment, just create the `powerbi_refresh_dataset.sh` and `credential_file.sh`, place it at any directory and create a CRON task to call `powerbi_refresh_dataset` as many time as you wish.

**Windows Host**

On windows you can do almost the same as on Linux, but you'll have to replace the content of shell script file by Power Shell command (google it) and use the `Scheduled Task` to regularly execute you Power Shell file.

Well, I think this would help you. I know it's not a complete answer as it will only works if you have a similar environment, but I hope that the final tips might help you.

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

**The Solution**

First let me resume the solution. I just putted a condition execution at the end of each query that checks if today is the day where new data must be uploaded or not. If yes, it returns the step to be executed, if not, it raises a error.
There is many ways to implement that and I'll go from the simplest form to the more complex one.

**Simplest Version: checking if it's the day to load new data directly at the query**

This is the simplest way to implement the solution, but, depending on your dataset it may not be the smartest one.

Lets say you have this foo query:

```
let
 step1 = ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 step10 = SomeFunction(Somevariable, someparameter)
in
 setp10
```

Now lets pretend you want that query to upload new data just on 1st day of the month. To do that, you just insert a condicional struction at `in` clause.

```
let
 step1 = ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 step10 = SomeFunction(Somevariable, someparameter)
in
 if Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 1 then setp10 else error "Today is not the day to load data"
```

At this example I just replaced the `setp10` at the return of the query by this piece of code:`if Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 1 then setp10 else error "Today is not the day to load data"`. By doing that, setp10 will be the result of this query only if this query is been executed at day 1st of the month, otherwise, it will return a error.

And here it's worthy some explanation. Power Query is not a script language that runs at the same order that it's declared. So the fact the condicional statement was placed at the end of the query doesn't mean that all code above will be executed before the error is launched. As Power Query just executes what's necessary, the `if...` statement it will probably be the first one to be executed. For more info about how Power Query works behind the scene, I stronlgy recomend you this reading: https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2018/02/28/4391/power-query-m-primer-part5-paradigm

**Using function**

Now lets move foward. Lets say that your Dataset set has not only one, but many queries and all of them needs to be executed only once a month. In this case, a smart way to do that is by using what all other programming languages have to reuse block of code: create a function!
For this, create a new Blank Query and paste this code on its body:

```
(step) =>
let
  result = if Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 1 then step else error "Today is not the day to load data"
in
  result
```

Now, at each query you'll call this function, sending the last setp as parameter. The function will check which day is today and return the same step passed as parameter if it's the day to load the data. Otherwise, it will return the error.
Bellow is the code of our query using our function called `check_if_upload`

```
let
 step1 = ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 step10 = SomeFunction(Somevariable, someparameter)
 step11 = check_if_upload(step10)
in
 step11
```

**Using parameters**

One final tip. As your query raises a error if today is not the day to upload day, it means that you can only test your ETL once a month, right? The error message also limite you to save you Power Query, which means that if you don't apply the modifications you can't upload the new Power Query version (having this implementations) to Power BI Service.
Well, you could change the value of the day verification into the function, but it's let's say, a little dummy.
A more ellegante way to change this parameter is by using parameters. So, lets do it. Create a parameter (I'll call it `Upload Day`) as a number type. Now, all you have to do is use this parameter at your function. It will look like this:

```
(step) =>
let
  result = if Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow()) = #"Upload Day" then step else error "Today is not the day to load data"
in
  result
```

That's it. Now you can change the upload day directly at Power BI Service, just changing this parameter at the dataset (click on dataset name and goes to Settings >> Parameters).

Hope you neiled it and that its helpful for you.

Best regards.

Comment: Will this work? Yes, but its super hacky and most organizations would not want an error reported every day that their data is not refreshing. I'd strongly recommend just scheduling an API call or using TMSL commands against your XMLA endpoint. Read Microsoft's recommendation of using both these options [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#data-refresh) .There are many tools out there that can do both of the options and can then be scheduled for whatever interval you want. If one of my developers came to me with this solution, I would not be happy...

Comment: You're write @trenton-ftw. It actually doesn't work as Power Service Dataset Refresh Schedule is inactivated after 4 erros in a row.
Thanks for your retrun.

Comment: I did not actually know that, but that is definitely a compelling reason to find another solution. As I mentioned, you can easily do this using a different scheduling tool (Task Scheduler or SQL Job Agent to name a few commons ones) paired with the options I mentioned and that won't require customizing your dataset to be specific to its intended refresh schedule.